# Drag and Drop VBA Alerts

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get an alert when I drag and drop from my browser for work into an excel spreadsheet. When I drag from one cell in excel into another and there is data in the cell it is asked, but not any other time. I am trying to add it to my existing code in a spreadsheet worksheet change sub, but having issues with the value as it is not copy and paste, so it is not on my clipboard. I tried to record a macro while doing it, but it only shows “ActiveSheet.Paste”, which if I have something on my clipboard it will paste that instead of the drag and drop value I wanted.

I found a code kind of what I wanted, but don’t want it copied from another cell, only the value that I dragged and dropped.

```
If Range("D1") <> "" Then
    Response = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite the existing data", vbYesNo)
End If
If Response = vbYes Then
    Range("A1").Copy Range("D1")
End If
```

I thought maybe is it possible to do this? In my spreadsheet I only have the code activated when column J is changed.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if Excel has the type of event that you would need to listen for .... you'd essentially need to either listen for a drag/drop event (which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist in Excel), or you'd need to be able to intercept a change to a cell's value and cancel the change if the user says they don't want to overwrite.  Excel does have a "change" event, but it doesn't have the inherent ability to "cancel" the command.  (You could perhaps try and leverage Application.Undo(), but that's probably a messy workaround, and could get the "change" event into an endless loop)

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can do what you want to do with the out of the box events etc. that ship with Excel. You may need to explore custom events (if applicable) or custom written add ins that might give you the ability to catch this type of event.

---

Consider the following testing I've just done on a new worksheet to establish which events fire in which order based on 'dragging and dropping' a cell to another cell.

Both subs are within the `Sheet1` code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Change " & Target.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Selection Change " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

If I have a value in Cell `A1` and I click and drag that cell to say `C5`, the results output as such:

> ```
> Change $A$1
> Change $C$5
> Selection Change $C$5
> ```

This shows the events fire in this order and targeting these cells:

> 1. `Worksheet_Change` event fires on the *source* cell.
> 2. `Worksheet_Change` event fires on the *destination* cell.
> 3. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event fires on the *destination* cell.

This presents us with the following considerations:

- The `Worksheet_Change` event fires twice, once with the initialisation of clicking and dragging the source cell and then again when you drop onto the destination cell.
- This makes a clean solution difficult as it's easy to program an infinite loop.
- `SelectionChange` only fires once so would be a bit easier to work with but you would need to work out feeding in the source range your are drag/dropping.

I had a go at working out *something* but I kept ending up with either infinite loops of `change/selectionchange` events firing or issues around catching the event before the application alerts fire etc. etc.